# How to find a real "poles" of a function?

Tags: plotting

I have a function whose plot is shown below,
[image]

I want to find approximate value of $x$ where this function have local infinities. I have tried using "FindMaximum", but that is not reliable as it gives correct value sometimes and require very close initial value to the actual answer. Is there any other way of finding that I am looking for?

Comment: What is the function?

Comment: It's a black box, however if I try to see what the function is then it's so big that its unreadable.

Comment: Maybe try to `FindRoot` when $1/f(x)$ is zero.

Comment: That's a good trick. I tried it, but there is again the same problem as the FindMaximum. If the initial value is very to actual value, then it is giving correct answer, but slight change in initial value is giving me $x$ very large.

Comment: Try `NMinimize` on $1/f(x)^2$ with a constraint on $x$ to limit the range of values. `NMinimize[{1/f[x]^2, -0.5<x<0.5},x]`

Comment: Tried this:
NMinimize[{$\frac{1}{Re[antisymrmyP[I*x]^2}$] && 0 < x && x < 1/2}, x]
the error was "NMinimize::nnum: The function value False is not a number at {x} = {-0.829053}."

Comment: Also tried this:
NMinimize[{$1/Re[antisymrmyP[I*x]^2]$, x \[Element] PositiveReals}, x]
Got the solution "{$1.31912*10^{-18}$, {x -> 5.82051}}"

Comment: Worst comes to worst, you might consider implementing a bisection method to locate your poles.

Comment: Try using [`FunctionDomain`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionDomain.html), e.g., `Cases[FunctionDomain[f[x], x], _?NumericQ, 2] // Union`

Comment: @sslucifer why did you add all those && signs? The syntax for NMinimize is `NMinimize[{objective, constraint1, constraint2, ..., constraintN}, variables]`. You want `NMinimize[{1/Re[antisymrmyP[I*x]]^2, 0<x<1/2}, x]`